# Grouping data by custom range in R (for example, 0-4, 1-5, 2-6, 3-7 and etc.)

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, aggregation, categorization

I'm using Titanic dataset from  https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic.

I want to make different age groups like "0-4", "1-5", "2-6", "3-7" and etc. and find out the age group where the percentage of survived is the highest. My age groups are within the integer interval [0,80]. The column "Age" in the original dataset also includes NAs. The column "Survived" contains the information if the person was survived or not (0 = No, 1 = Yes).

I was trying to solve this problem like this but it didn't work. I will be grateful for any help.

```
for(i in 0:80){
max= -Inf
x[i]<-(sum(subset(dataset, Age < (i+5) & Age >= i, select = "Survived")))/(length(which(dataset$Age < (i+5) & dataset$Age>= i)))
if (x[i] > max) max <- x[i]
return(max, i, i+5)}
```

Comment: Your groups overlap, `"0-4", "1-5", "2-6", "3-7"`. A value of `Age == 3` goes into what group, all of these?

Comment: Yes, Age == 3 falls into several age groups. I understand that it is ridiculous. But still if there any possibility to write a loop or make a table with groups like this to find out  the persentage of survived for every age group with step=5?

Answer (score 2):

First I will make up some data.

```
set.seed(1234)   # make it reproducible
Age <- sample(c(NA, 1:80), 200, TRUE)
Survived <- sample(0:1, 200, TRUE)
```

Now the code. Define a function to `cut` the input into groups, and `lapply` that function to each group start, from `0` to `3`.

```
fun <- function(i, x){
    as.character(cut(x, breaks = seq(i, 80, by = 5), include.lowest = TRUE))
}

res <- unlist(lapply(0:3, fun, Age))
table(res)

res_surv <- unlist(lapply(0:3, fun, Age[Survived == 1]))
table(res_surv)
```

If you want percentages, you can do it with

```
tbl_surv <- table(res_surv)
100*tbl_surv/sum(tbl_surv)
```

Answer (score 2):

The OP has requested to

> find out the age group where the percentage of survived is the highest

There is one possible solution which uses a *non-equi join*:

```
library(data.table)
library(titanic)
dataset <- as.data.table(titanic_train)
delta <- 4
max_age <- 80
dataset[
  .(lower = seq(0, max_age - delta), upper = seq(delta, max_age)), 
  on = .(Age >= lower, Age <= upper), .SD[, .N, by = Survived], by = .EACHI][
    , total.N := sum(N), by = Age][, share := N / total.N][]
```

> ```
>      Age Age Survived  N total.N     share
>   1:   0   4        1 27      40 0.6750000
>   2:   0   4        0 13      40 0.3250000
>   3:   1   5        0 13      37 0.3513514
>   4:   1   5        1 24      37 0.6486486
>   5:   2   6        0 12      33 0.3636364
>  ---                                      
> 137:  72  76        0  1       1 1.0000000
> 138:  73  77        0  1       1 1.0000000
> 139:  74  78        0  1       1 1.0000000
> 140:  75  79       NA  1       1 1.0000000
> 141:  76  80        1  1       1 1.0000000
> ```

The result so far shows that age groups with only one passenger who has survived have the highest survival rate of 100%. This is trivial and probably not the result the OP is looking for. Either `delta` has to be enlarged or a threshold on the absolute number of passengers per age group has to be applied, e.g., `total.N > 2`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to tabulate everything by age, then turn those into groups. Then use the `lag()` function recursively to add each set of five rows. Assuming the dataframe (`df`) has two columns, `Age` and `Survived` (0 or 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Age) %>% 
  summarize(n = n(), Survived = sum(Survived)) %>% 
  arrange(Age) %>% 
  mutate(Age_Group = paste0(Age-4, "-", Age)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(n, Survived), 
  funs(. + lag(.) + lag(lag(.)) + lag(lag(lag(.))) + lag(lag(lag(lag(.)))))) %>% 
  mutate(SurvivalRate = Survived/n) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(n)) %>% 
  select(-Age)
```